# How to define a query parameter in OpenAPI that must be empty or not present?

Tags: boolean, openapi

In the OpenAPI specification, there is an `allowEmptyValue` property ([documentation](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/#nullable)) that indicates a query parameter MAY be sent with no value. Their example given is

```yaml
parameters:
  - in: query
    name: metadata
    schema:
      type: boolean
      allowEmptyValue: true
```

This implies a query could be done as `/?metadata`, but could also be done as `/?metadata=false` or `/?metadata=true`.

But how can I specify a query parameter that is "boolean" in that it's either "on" or "off", but the logic for determining that is if it's present at all, it's "on", and if it's not defined at all, it's "off"? As in, the only two permissible values are:

- `/?metadata`: The "metadata" value is `true`/"on"
- `/?`: The "metadata" value is `false`/"off"

Notably, doing `/?metadata=ANYTHING` is considered `true`/"on", even `/?metadata=false`, `/?metadata=0`, `/?metadata=no`, or `/?metadata=off` are all considered `true`/"on" (because the parameter is present in the request at all; doesn't matter what the value is set to).

Answer (score 0):

OpenAPI Specification doesn't explain how to describe flag-like query parameters. There's a related discussion on GitHub:
[Not clear how to describe a “flag” parameter in OpenAPI](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/1782)

In that discussion, one of the participants proposes using an [extension](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/openapi-extensions/) like `x-isFlag` to describe such parameters. For example:

```yaml
parameters:
  - in: query
    name: metadata
    schema: {}
    required: false
    allowEmptyValue: true
    x-isFlag: true
```

Note that `x-` extensions are just metadata, so `x-isFlag` won't have actual effect in OpenAPI-based tools (such as Swagger UI, OpenAPI Generator, and others) unless someone implements support for this extension.